# Help me understand the phrase from the image: "to nervously ask you to prom"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Again asking for Your help as native English speakers. I'm studying English, I really like it. I am not a native English speaker, my native language is Russian. For me not understand the phrase: "to nervously ask you to prom". Please explain what is meant.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [prom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prom) is a graduation party in an American school. The students wear formal clothes and usually go with a partner from their class. Many teenage boys are lacking in social skills and are nervous about asking a girl to go to the prom with them: this fits with the body posture of these pangolins, with their heads bowed and hands together.

Answer (score 1):

Владимир, look, a [**prom**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prom) is '*a formal party held for older students at the end of the school year, at which there is dancing*' and in Russian it is close to "**выпускной вечер**" or "**студенческий бал**".

JavaLatte said it correctly that "**many teenage boys are shy and nervous about asking a girl to dance with them *(go to the prom with them)***". In Russia the same thing often happens. I remember my school years. I used to sit on a bench or stand in a corner with my head down and my hands together *(I was often rubbing them)*. if you look at the baby pangolins you can see that they keep their heads bowed and the fingers and hands together *(it looks like they are nervous and shy)*.

Comment: Very nice to meet you! I will arrive in Krasnodar this summer.

Comment: @Владимир I'll be glad to speak to you on vk if you want: https://vk.com/sovereign89